# Javafx: when deleting an item from a ListView almost all items disappear from the list, but reappear when refreshing the screen

Tags: java, listview, javafx

If there's anything hard to understand I apologize, english is not my native language.

I'm trying to do a screen using JavaFX where there's a ListView, and in the list cell there's a button to delete the correspondent item, but when I delete the item all items but one disappears from the ListView, but only visually, they still continue in the list (if I refresh the list by changing the screen all items that should be in the list reappear).

This is the code for the delete button:

```
    @FXML
    public void deletePlan(ActionEvent event) {
        ButtonType all = new ButtonType("All revisions");
        ButtonType rev = new ButtonType("Revision 0" + model.getSelectedPlant()[0]);
        ButtonType cancel = new ButtonType("Back", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
        
        Alert confirm = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Delete all plans from " + plan.getPlanName() + " or just Revision 0" + model.getSelectedPlant()[0] + "?",all, rev, cancel);
            
        confirm.setTitle("Delete plan");
        confirm.setHeaderText(null);
        
        Optional<ButtonType> result = confirm.showAndWait();
        
        if(!result.isPresent() || result.get() == ButtonType.CLOSE) {
            Alert inf = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            
            inf.setTitle("Warning");
            inf.setHeaderText(null);
            inf.setContentText("Operation cancelled.");
            inf.show();
        } else if(result.get() == all) {
            project.deletePlan(plan.getPlanNumber());
        } else if(result.get() == rev) {
            plan.deleteRevision(model.getSelectedPlant()[0]);
        }
    }
```

It happens only when I use the "all" option, which executes "project.deletePlan(plan.getPlanNumber());". The option "rev" is working as it should.
plan.getPlanNumber() just returns a int that I use to identify the document I want to remove from the list so I think is not necessary to put the code here.

Below is the list screenshot (the one marked with red), the first cell is how it looks when the cell is selected.
[Screenshot 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ajb0.png)

The "Revisão 01" button is working normally, it executes the "rev" option from the Alert I've mentioned earlier, but when I press the button "Todos" which executes the "all" option is when the problem occurs.
[Screenshot 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utStb.png)

I've deleted the first item of the list, but all items except the second disappeared. But, when I close the "Plantas" pane and then reopen it the ListView shows all the items correctly.
[Screenshot 03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7JlP.png)
[Screenshot 04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNyTT.png)

I've tried using list.refresh() after the delete, I've tried clearing the ListView and then repopulate it but nothing worked. I've used a print function to print all items of the list before and after the delete and everything was correct, this happens only visually.

Can someone help me with this? I don't know why this happens.

Edit: As requested by jewelsea I made a minimal reproducible example, but I thought there was too much archives so I put all it needed in a git repository i'll be linking below.

[Repository](https://github.com/CaiusT/TestApp.git)

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so this can be replicated through copy and paste.  I didn't read your complete question, but generally, issues like this are often caused by incorrect implementation of an updateItem method in a cell factory for the list.  I don't know if that is the case for you, as I don't see the code for how you define the list cells and set the items on it.

Comment: Your code looks overcomplicated. I would do something like `plantasList.removeIf(t -> t.getPlantaNum() == num);`

Comment: @jewelsea sorry it took too long and thanks for the answer. I just edited with a link to a repository with the code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SedJ601 thanks for the tip, I didn't know about that method

Comment: where are the "Revisão 01" and "Todos" buttons? i cant see them in that image...also, what list doesnt display correctly? the one with "Aquasan, arrozeira pelotas,..."? or the one with "Rev 02, rev 01"? all in all your description of the problem is very hard to understand, plus in your code, what is project?, what is plan?, what is model? we dont know and that makes it impossible to help you

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel "Revisão 01" and "Todos" buttons are in the Screenshot 02 right in the center of the image, in the alert box. The list with problem is the one surrounded with a red line in the Screenshot 01, the list with "01 Fluxograma, 02 Localização, ...". Project, Plan and Model are just classes inside the program, the codes for them are in the git repository i linked in the end of the question.

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel the problem is that when I press the Delete button (the one with a trash can in screenshot 01) and them press the "Todos" button (from screenshot 02) it should delete the "01 Fluxograma" from the List and then update the ListView showing only the remaining items "02 Localização", "03 Layout" and "04 Vista A", but what's happening is that, after the delete, the ListView updates and only shows "02 Localização" (as you can see in Screenshot 03), but when I close the TitledPane "Plantas" and them open it again the ListView shows the items correctly (as you can see in screenshot 04)

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/sedj601/CampingAppCopyTwo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/camping/PrimaryController.java) can help. Press `Control+f` to search for `delete`. Those delete methods should help. Also, search for `listview` to see how some of the listviews are set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong, so I'm answering my own question.

Like jewelsea said, I did a wrong implementation of the updateItem method in the cell factory.

This is the wrong code:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(PlanInfo plan, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(plan, empty);
    
    if(empty || plan == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if(loader == null) {
            loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("planListCell.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch(IOException io) {
                Logger.getLogger(PlanListCell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, io);
            }

            this.plan = plan;
            
            planName.setText(plan.getPlanName());
            planNumber.setText("0" + String.valueOf(plan.getPlanNumber()));
            
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(planPane);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the right code:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(PlanInfo plan, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(plan, empty);
    
    if(empty || plan == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if(loader == null) {
            loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("planListCell.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);
            
            try {
                loader.load();
            } catch(IOException io) {
                Logger.getLogger(PlanListCell.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, io);
            }
        }
        
 /*-->*/this.plan = plan;
            
        planName.setText(plan.getPlanName());
        planNumber.setText("0" + String.valueOf(plan.getPlanNumber()));
            
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(planPane);/*<--*/
    }
}
```

That block of code that I pointed to with the arrows, I placed it incorrectly inside the if(loader==null){} block, which was causing the ListCell rendering to behave strangely.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you are using two planList objects, one in the controller and another one in the project model...you should either use only one, or re-init the model after deleting the plan

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand. The planList you talking about is the ListView in the controller? If yes i only have one, i didn't found another of this object. I do have a plansList too, but that is an ObservableList. And about re-initing the model, how can i do that?

Comment: you delete plan from project...you never delete plan from ObservableList

Comment: project is an object from ProjectInfo class, and the ObservableList is inside project